# Best method to backup SQLITE3 database so that the backupfile is reduced in size

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to take a backup of all the sqlite3 databases and restore it sometime in future. I have only one table in a database. The table contains blob data. The backup file should be as minimum in size as possible.
Things I tried,

1. Used .dump, however the size of the dumpfile did not reduce
2. As I am using Python, I decoded the data and stored it into a shelve file. The shelve file size is reduced about 16K.

Is there any method, so that the dumpfile size can be reduced further?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered file compression? like:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite .dump | xz > backup.sql.xz
```

xz -9 would have the best compression rate. -6 is default.

I got curious, so i tested:

```
# insert image from terminal, described at:
# https://objectiveseesharp.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/storing-an-image-in-sqlite3-as-a-blob/
sqlite3 foo.sql 'create table image  ( img blob );'
echo "insert into image values ( X'$(hexdump -ve '1/1 "%0.2X"' hs-2015-02-a-hires_jpg.jpg)' );" | sqlite3 foo.sql
```

- img is 21M
- database 21M
- uncompressed backup 41M
- compressed backup 21M
- compressed database 21M

using image from http://hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/2015/02/image/a/warn/

Comment: `.dump` creates text output, which is especially inefficient for blobs. It might be a better idea to compress the original database file.

Comment: I used all the 3 methods. My original db is 136K. It compressed to 104K. Can I compress it further, at least to half the original size. Is there any other way? Thanks for all the responses. It did help a lot!

Comment: compression rate boils down to what kind of data you have in your blob's. If it is already compressed images (like jpeg) I dont think you can expect a 50% compression rate.